# Iterate over a DF with variables from itself and another DF

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I'm working on a project that examines concentration of clients, where i currently have the conversion/maths in place. however am struggling to get them to overlay.

I have a DF (portfolio) of a portfolio (21k entities) with their longitudes and latitudes converted into radians for the maths.

I then have a separate DF (Grid_ref) with a list of 441 coordinates (21 x 21 grid), this DF have two blank columns for  the total number of Clients within 250m and total value of the clients.

I am trying to iterate over the portfolio def to calculate the above (count and value) however keep getting an error (type error series to float)

i suspect i know where the issue is however haven't been able to work out a solution (my python knowledge is fairly limited).

Sample of each df:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

portfolio = pd.DataFrame({
    'name':['a', 'b', 'c' ],  
    'value':[10000, 100000, 1000000], 'convertedlat': [80.9090170235, 80.9266727742, 80.9050586168], 'convertedlong' : [ -0.11894069786 , -0.19952254942, -0.04219158933]})

Grid_ref = pd.DataFrame({'Lat': [0.898991160550, 0.899145218644,0.898943139573], 'Long':[-0.001359632426, -0.002279714596,-0.000511374166], 'count':[0,0,0], 'value': [0,0,0]})
```

from the above the 1 and 3rd clients should count in the 1st and 3rd Grid_ref's, with the 2nd being >250m.

the maths behind this true/false for within 250m:

```
`2* 6371 *((sin((portfolio['convertedlat'] - Grid_ref['Lat'])/2)**2 + cos(Grid_ref['Lat'])*cos(portfolio['convertedlat'])*sin((portfolio['convertedlong']-Grid_ref['Long'])/2)**2)**(1/2))  <= 0.250
`
```

as there are 4 arguments required for the calculation, I have looked at nesting loops to take the x,y from Grid_ref and a,b from portfolio however this feels like bad practice due to potential time resources as the data sets expand. I have tried to use a lambda however i am unfamiliar with utilising these with 4 variables across 2 DF's.

my current solution is using the below function:

```
def in250m(a, b):
    dist = 2 * 6371 * ((math.sin((portfolio['convertedlat'] - a) / 2) ** 2 + math.cos(a) *
                           math.cos(portfolio['convertedlat']) * (math.sin((portfolio['convertedlong']) - b) / 2)**2)**(1 / 2)) <= max_dist
    return dist

grid['count'] = (portfolio['convertedlat'].apply (lambda x: 1 if in250m(a, b) else 0)).sum()
```

however get the error "TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>", which  i believe is caused by in250m function calling the entire series for (Portfolio['convertedlat'] rather then the unique values. i was hoping that applying the lambda to the series would help but i am clearly missing something fundamental in the function.

i fully suspect i am making my potential solution more complex then it needs to be. i have omitted the value function as this should be a simply amend to the above to move from count to sum and on the value

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, the error is caused by `in250`m function calling the entire series rather then the unique values.

The code for `apply` method also looks confused.
Typically the syntax is something llike that:

```
df["YOUR COLUMN"].apply(lambda x: func(x) + 1)
```

Which means that for each value in `"YOUR COLUMN"` the value of `func(x) + 1` is calculated. In your snippet argument `x` is not even envolved in calculations: `lambda x: 1 if in250m(a, b) else 0`, so even if the error did not occur, your calculation would totally disregard the column it was applied to and do the same thing for each value.

So you said that you need to evaluate for each grid point how many users are near. Let's do exactly that.
We will write a function that takes grid lat and lon as arguments and calculate how many users are near, and apply it to `Grid_ref` dataframe. We'll call it `get_user_count(lat, lon)`.

In that function we will apply your `in250m` to each row, therefore all the arguments will be scalars and no error will occur.

`.sum()` in the end of `get_user_count` will return an integer for each `Grid_ref` row.

Code:

```
def in250m(a, b, lat, lon):
    dist = 2 * 6371 * ((math.sin((lat - a) / 2) ** 2 + math.cos(a) *
                           math.cos(lat) * (math.sin((lon) - b) / 2)**2)**(1 / 2)) <= max_dist
    return int(dist)

def get_user_count(lat, lon):
    return portfolio \
        .apply(lambda row: in250m(lat, lon, row['convertedlat'], row['convertedlong']), axis=1) \
        .sum()

Grid_ref.apply(lambda row: get_user_count(row["Lat"], row["Long"]), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
0    0
1    0
2    0
```

Comment: Thanks, with some re-working have managed to get your solution to work in live, but does seem to take a while to run through the data but believe this is linked more to the cals.

i do have one followup query, which i appreciate you may not have time to assist with.

is there a simple way to collate the users that make up the count and output this into another DF using the grid ref as a common identifier? am just thinking future development of being able to drill the grid_ref with the count and value and then being able to open that up to see which users make up the total?